# MySQL - Order accented vs not-accented characters, non-accented first

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, collation, accent-sensitive

**Note that this question is NOT about *searching* for (non)accented characters.**

Suppose I have a table where there is a column `name`, with collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

This collation works perfectly for the purpose of selecting the base selection

in a case-**in**sensitive, accent-**in**sensitive way.

#### The problem is that I need to order the results in an accent-*sensitive* and case-*in*sensitive way.

The purpose of this is to select every name starting with some character/string and sort them "alphabetically", first should be not-accented, then accented.

From selection e.g.:

```
Črpw
Cewo
céag
čefw
```

The final results should be:

```
Cewo
céag -- because accented e is more than non-accented
čefw  
Črpw -- because r is more than e
```

Note that `c`/`C` < `č`/`Č` , but lower/upper cases are handled as equals.

I tried searching for this problem, but there are only popping ***similar*** questions or questions about searching, which is not the case, the searching itself is fine.

From mentioned I've tried this test query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 'Črpw' as t
UNION SELECT 'Cewo'
UNION SELECT 'céag'
UNION SELECT 'čefw')virtual
ORDER BY t COLLATE utf8mb4_czech_ci ASC
```

Which produces something very ***similar*** to what I want

```
céag
Cewo
čefw
Črpw
```

But note that `é` gets ordered before `e`.

Is there a way how to get to the results order I want to have?

*Using: MySQL 5.5.54 (Debian)*

Comment: The only collations available for utf8 (until version 8.0) are case_sensitive and accent_sensitive.  I don't think you could use `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` to help out.

Comment: @RickJames yep, I've tried that too... Anyway, this seems to vary across the letters, e.g. `é` gets before `e` but `ř` goes *after* `r` ...

Comment: According to my notes, c < č and r < ř, but e = é.  These are, as far as I know, "correct" for Czech.  It may _appear_ that e > é, but that may be because the ordering is unpredictable.  For example `'céag' < 'Cewo'` because `'a' < 'w'`, which is noticed after deciding that `'cé' = 'Ce'`.

Comment: utf8[mb4]_czech_ci differs from other collations mostly by having the characters (r/c/s/z) accented with caron coming after the letter plain or other accents.  `ch` is also different in that it comes between `h` and `i`; ditto for Slovak.  [_More details_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html)